# Required field only when editing

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using a Form in Django app.
This form is used to set a value and again to change it.

When changing it, a reason needs to be specified, but not when setting it.

I change the display of the field 'reason' to none when the value is None, but since the field is `required`, the user can't submit the form because the field is not filled.

When clicking on confirm:

[image: Please fill this field]

Also, when editing, the value is pre filled, it also displays an error because the 'reason' field is not filled.

Before clicking anywhere:

[image: Before clisking anywhere]

What can I do so that the field is only required when editing?

EDIT: code

view

```
def change_grade(request, grade_id):
    grade = get_object_or_404(Grade, id=grade_id)
    if(request.method=='POST'):
        form = GradeForm(request.POST)
        if(form.is_valid()):
            #save it
    if(grade.grade is None):
        form = GradeForm()
    else:
        form = GradeForm({'grade':grade.grade})
    return render(...)
```

form

```
class GradeForm(forms.Form):
    grade = forms.DecimalField()
    reason = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textearea(), required = True)
```

in template

```
{%if grade.grade is None%}
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("id_reason").parentElement.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
{%endif%}
```

EDIT2: I have found a workaround. I set the field as not required and I set it to required with JS in my template.

```
{%if sub_course_grade.grade is None%}
<script>
        window.onload = function(){
                reason_field = document.getElementById("id_reason");
                reason_field.parentElement.style.display = "none";
        }
</script>
{%else%}
<script>
        window.onload = function(){
                reason_field = document.getElementById("id_reason");
                reason_field.setAttribute("required", "");
        }
</script>
{%endif%}
```

I know this is not optimal as the user can edit the html and not send the reason, but this is good enough for this application.

Comment: Could you share the appropriate `view` that handles this?

Comment: Can you provide your form code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override your edit form, and added it to your view

```
class EditGradeForm(forms.Form):
    grade = forms.DecimalField(required = False)
    reason = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textearea(), required = False)
```

or you can override

```
 def __init__ (self, grade=None, *args, **kwargs):
     if grade:
         # put your code
```